# Neo4j query run at specific time

Tags: neo4j, asp.net-core

Currently, I'm making an application with asp.net core and neo4j graph database.

My application provides an account registration system, which send an activation code to user registered email and after 24 hours, if user doesn't click on the active link, the account will be deleted.

My question is : can I write a trigger in neo4j graph database to automatically runs after 24 hours after a node has been created to check whether it has been verified or not and delete it if it hasn't.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`apoc` job management](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#job-management):

1) Create user:

```
CREATE (U:User {created_at: timestamp(), activated: false})
```

2) Running periodic task (every hour), which takes a list of non-activated users, and checks the activation time, and remove those who do not activate account within 24 hours:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.repeat('name',
    'MATCH (U:User {activated: false}) 
         WHERE timestamp() - U.created_at > 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
     DETACH DELETE U', 
60 * 60)
```

Comment: how does one cancel a periodic task that was started via apoc.periodic.repea?

Comment: @Alberts You can use `apoc.periodic.cancel` procedure.

Comment: just to be precise @Alberts query to cancel periodic task would be `CALL apoc.periodic.cancel('name')` where `name` is the name of the repeated task

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions that handle this :

First one is a neo4j plugin called `neo4j-expire` where you can set a `time-to-live` timestamp on a node and this node will be automatically expired/deleted by the plugin at the given time :

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-expire

The second solution is to create a Cypher query that performs this check and register it with the job management procedures available in `neo4j-apoc` https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_job_management